How can I prevent add duplicate items to APEX_COLLECTION
I want to create laboratory tests order and I created apex collection ,
I need to check if test already exists in the collection I need to show message says
Test already exists .
I tried this code :
Declare 
v_seq_id number;
v_test_no number; 

begin 

if not apex_collection.collection_exists('TESTS') then 

apex_collection.create_collection('TESTS');
end if;

select seq_id , c001 into v_seq_id,v_test_no 
from apex_collections 
where collection_name='TESTS'
and  c001 = :P58_TEST_NO;
exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
THEN v_seq_id :=0 ; 


if v_seq_id != 0 THEN 
v_test_no := v_test_no ;
end if;
end;
apex_collection.add_member(

    p_collection_name => 'TESTS',
    p_c001 => :P58_TEST_NO , 
    p_c002 => :P58_TEST_NAME , 
    p_c003 => :P58_SECTION , 
    p_c004 => :P58_TESTPRICE , 
    p_c005 => :P58_TESTVAT , 
    p_c006 => :P58_TESTTOTAL
);

I created the collection then I need to check if test exists I need to prevent add this test
another time and show message the test already exist
 if v_seq_id != 0 THEN 
    v_test_no := v_test_no ;
    end if;
    end;

see the image now its duplicate the test

how can I do that and thank you in advance
I created the code on dynamic action on the item P58_TEST_NO execute server side code , now I created the validation on same item P58_TEST_NO and its working when I click on SAVE ORDER button and submit the page, but I need it before that for example when I select test albumin it will add to collection if I select it again I need the validation on page item prevent and dont add the test again into collection

see image please albumin added 2 times I need to add one time only and prevent add it again when select the test not validate when submit the page and click SAVE ORDER button

You're not mentioning how this process is invoked so I'm assuming this is a form where the "Save Order" submits the page and this process is invoked in the "Processing" section. This is the "APEX way".
To avoid duplicates, just create a validation of type "No rows returned" with source
SELECT seq_id
  FROM apex_collections 
 WHERE collection_name='TESTS' AND
       c001 = :P58_TEST_NO;

and error message "Test already exists ".
Then in the page process just execute the call to apex_collection.add_member. If the validation fails the page processing will stop and this page process will not be executed.

I created this code on dynamic action on the item P58_TEST_NO execute server side code , now I created the validation on same item P58_TEST_NO and its working when I click on SAVE ORDER button , but I need it before that for example when I select test albumin it will add to collection if I select it again I need the validation on page item prevent add again to collection

When is dynamic action executed ?

Execute servier-side-code , thank you I solved it in different way just apex_collection.update_member_attribute

I'm adding another answer to comment on your own answer just to point out how the EXCEPTION block works in pl/sql (docs). The syntax is:
BEGIN
  <code>
EXCEPTION WHEN <some named exception or OTHERS> THEN
  <code to execute when exception is reached>
END;

This block above can be nested within pl/sql. The following is valid:
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    <code>
  EXCEPTION WHEN <some named exception or OTHERS> THEN
    <code to execute when exception is reached>
  END;
EXCEPTION WHEN <some named exception or OTHERS> THEN
  <code to execute when exception is reached>
END;


In your answer there is the following snippet:
and  c001 = :P58_TEST_NO;
exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
THEN v_seq_id :=0 ; 

This means that everything below the line exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND will only be executed when the NO_DATA_FOUND is raised. That is probably note the way you intend that code to work.
This can be solved by using a nested pl/sql block:
...
end if;

-- select sequence and quantity to validate test exist or not 

BEGIN
  SELECT seq_id , c004 into v_seq_id,v_qty 
    FROM apex_collections 
   WHERE collection_name='TESTS'
         AND c001 = :P58_TEST_NO;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    v_seq_id :=0 ; 
END;

-- if test exist then update the quantity only if you need to increase item quantity 
-- use v_qty+1 else use v_qty+0 
...


I solved it in the following way
I added quantity column and used
apex_collection.update_member_attribute

this is the complete code used in the item P58_TEST_NO dynamic action used Execute server side code
Declare 
v_seq_id number;
v_qty number;

begin 

-- first step create apex collection  
if not apex_collection.collection_exists('TESTS') then 

apex_collection.create_collection('TESTS');
end if;

-- select sequence and quantity to validate test exist or not 
select seq_id , c004 into v_seq_id,v_qty 
from apex_collections 
where collection_name='TESTS'
and  c001 = :P58_TEST_NO;
exception WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
THEN v_seq_id :=0 ; 

-- if test exist then update the quantity only if you need to increase item quantity 
-- use v_qty+1 else use v_qty+0 

if v_seq_id != 0 THEN 
v_qty := v_qty+0 ;

-- update item quantity only if item already exist in the collection 

apex_collection.update_member_attribute (
    p_collection_name => 'TESTS',
    p_seq => v_seq_id , 
    p_attr_number => 4,
    p_attr_value => v_qty
);

else 
-- if item not exist add it 
apex_collection.add_member(

    p_collection_name => 'TESTS',
    p_c001 => :P58_TEST_NO , 
    p_c002 => :P58_TEST_NAME , 
    p_c003 => :P58_SECTION , 
    p_c004 => :P58_QTY,
    p_c005 => :P58_TESTPRICE , 
    p_c006 => :P58_TESTVAT , 
    p_c007 => :P58_TESTTOTAL 
);

end if;
end;

